# Could not find gem while deploying using capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, capistrano

I'm trying to deploy my app in staging using capistrano.

When I run `docker-compose run web cap staging deploy` I get this error :

> > Could not find capistrano-harrow-0.5.3 in any of the sources
> >     Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

However, I already `bundle install`. This is my files :

**Gemfile**

```
group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'capistrano',                require: false
  gem 'capistrano-bundler',       require: false
  gem 'capistrano-nc', '~> 0.1',  require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rails',         require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rails-console'
  gem 'capistrano-rvm', require: false
  gem 'capistrano3-delayed-job', '~> 1.0'
  gem 'capistrano3-puma', require: false
  gem 'letter_opener'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'rails-erd'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
```

**gemfile.lock**

```
    capistrano (3.7.2)
      airbrussh (>= 1.0.0)
      capistrano-harrow
      i18n
      rake (>= 10.0.0)
      sshkit (>= 1.9.0)
    capistrano-bundler (1.2.0)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      sshkit (~> 1.2)
    capistrano-harrow (0.5.3)
    capistrano-nc (0.1.4)
      capistrano (~> 3.0)
      terminal-notifier (~> 1.6)
    capistrano-rails (1.2.2)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      capistrano-bundler (~> 1.1)
    capistrano-rails-console (2.2.0)
      capistrano (>= 3.5.0, < 4.0.0)
      sshkit-interactive (~> 0.2.0)
    capistrano-rvm (0.1.2)
      capistrano (~> 3.0)
      sshkit (~> 1.2)
    capistrano3-delayed-job (1.7.3)
      capistrano (~> 3.0, >= 3.0.0)
      daemons (~> 1.2.4)
    capistrano3-puma (1.2.1)
      capistrano (~> 3.0)
      puma (>= 2.6)
```

**deploy.rb**

```
lock '3.10.0'

set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.3.3'

set :default_stage,   'staging'
set :stages,          %w(staging production)
...
```

Comment: Can you try `bundle update capistrano-harrow` ?

Comment: That did the trick ! :) Thank you